# Node.js - how to read a long string (over 10000 characters) from process.stdin?

Tags: node.js, stream, stdin, readline

For one programming exercise I need to read a long string (over 10000 characters) from `process.stdin`. (node 6.11.0, Win 10)

if I use `process.stdin` or `readline`, I am stuck at the limit of number of characters I can actually type - the command prompt actually stops taking any input after about 2700 characters, untill I press Enter. But the point is that it has to be one long line, without \n characters.

What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer, this code works:

```
let readline = require('readline');
let rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    terminal: true
});

function readLine (line) {
    //process your line, which could be very very long
}

rl.on('line', readLine);
```

The trick is to use `terminal: true`. When you use it, you can't see your input while typing, but it gets to the `readLine` function alright, and can be very long. If you use `terminal:false`, then you can see what you type, but the input is limited with about 2.700 characters.