# How to read a very long line from Terminal input in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read input from a terminal in Node JS. The input consists of multiple lines, with one line being very long (100k characters). Ex.:

```
5
50000
693647286 425883727 648263876 ... // the long line
```

However, the long line is being cut off when using the following approach to read the input:

```
'use strict';
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function(line) {
    console.log('Line: ', line);
    inputString += line;
});
```

I also tried other approaches described on StackOverflow, such as using readline. This approach hangs my terminal entirely:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line){
    console.log(line);
})
```

And readFileSync, which also cuts off the line input:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var stdinBuffer = fs.readFileSync(0); // STDIN_FILENO = 0
console.log(stdinBuffer.toString());
```

Would there be any other way to read the input line by line from the terminal without loosing data on the long input?

Comment: What happens if you set terminal to `true` in your second approach, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49002481/5156280) ?

Comment: Same thing. Regardless if terminal set to true or false, when I paste the input into terminal, it prints the line character by character, sort of infinitely. If I remove output setting and console.log, it seems to freeze. After the input nothing happens for a while and I I can not close the line with Ctrl + D nor with Ctrl + C.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65985833/handle-huge-amount-of-data-in-node-js-through-stdin

Answer (score 0):

So it has been a while since I did NodeJS but these type of questions are really interesting to me! You are indeed right about the terminal freezing when inputting large amounts of data (my windows terminal went crazy when trying to input `>100k 'A'`s).

Looking around at different links such as [Handle huge amount of data in node.js through stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65985833/handle-huge-amount-of-data-in-node-js-through-stdin) or [Node.js - how to read a long string (over 10000 characters) from process.stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991376/node-js-how-to-read-a-long-string-over-10000-characters-from-process-stdin?noredirect=1&lq=1) I couldn't really make it work with input that large. Instead I started looking at how the [`process.stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) in NodeJS worked which made me notice this: [process.stdin.fd](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processstdinfd)

With a file descriptor I was able to read data of that size. I provide the code below which worked for me:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Open a fd for reading
const fd = process.stdin.fd;

// Buffer to store the read data
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(200000); // 100k should be enough here but... :D

totalBytesRead = 0

function readFromDescriptor(fd) {
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, (err, bytesRead, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error reading from file descriptor:', err);
      } else {
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
          totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
          console.log('Read', bytesRead, 'bytes:'); // , data.slice(0, bytesRead).toString('utf-8')
        } else {
          console.log('Reached end of fd. Total bytes read:', totalBytesRead);
          fs.closeSync(fd);
        }
  
        // Continue reading
        readFromDescriptor(fd);
      }
    });
  }

readFromDescriptor(fd);
```

Now I am not printing the data that was read but only the bytes read. You can just include the commented part at the console.log if you would also want to see what has been written to stdin.

**NOTE:** For some reason I had an issue copying:

```
A
AAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

from my clipboard but writing `A` and hitting enter and then pasting the rest seemed to work just fine!

```
> A
**ENTER**
**PASTE**
AAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

Comment: This produced: `Error reading from file descriptor: [Error: EAGAIN: resource temporarily unavailable, read]`. node 18, linux.

Comment: @panta82 I think that is related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362369/stdin-read-fails-on-some-input ?

Comment: @panta82 sorry I only tried this on windows but I think the SO post above should help with that error.

Answer (score 0):

That could be consequence of [high watermark](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablereadablehighwatermark) configuration that is going to stream the file in chunks.

A simple solution that should work regardless of configuration is to collect the chunks `on('data')` and use the results `on('end')`.

```
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8')

lines = ['']

process.stdin.on('data', chunk => {
    let l0 = lines.pop()
    for(const subline of chunk.split('\n')){
        lines.push(l0 + subline)
        l0 = ''
    }
})

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
    for(const line of lines){
        console.log(line.length)
    }
})
```

Comment: Why do you need `fs` here and doesn't this solution have the same problem when reading a line > 100k characters?

Comment: Thank you @darclander I don't need `fs` here. And no, this solution doesn't have the line length limitation.

Comment: In my experiments, the output still gets cut off in the linux terminal. The test text: https://qtext.io/firn

Comment: so you are trying to paste in the terminal? I was supposing you were doing `cat input-file.txt | node read-file.js`

Comment: @Bob yes, paste gets blocked after a certain number of characters.

Comment: The problem is the terminal not nodejs. In this case the first comment in your question points to the right direction.

Comment: @Bob I was also thinking it was a limit in the terminal but as I provided in my answer I could paste >100k characters using a file descriptor.

Comment: but why are you using `terminal: false` in your code.

Comment: @Bob sorry I think you are confusing us with OP? Op is not the bounty giver nor me :o I was talking about my answer

Comment: Well, so if you were exploring this out of curiosity, I would say it is not a problem with NodeJS, it is a problem with the terminal itself. The terminal receives the text from the clipboard and passes to NodeJS, but the terminal has a limitation with long lines. The solution is to not use the terminal for this. The terminal was not made to paste tons of text...

Comment: @Bob why would there be a limit in the terminal? If you use [read()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) you could in theory read up to 4 gigabytes from user input?

Comment: Did you test it? If so why cat can't handle the long lines?

Comment: @Bob yes in my answer below I used a fd to input more than 100k characters via the clipboard. Cat should be able to handle it I think...